# IE8 - .on() function in JQuery is not supported in ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

Hi i am using **[cropit](http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/)** plugin for cropping the image in my project. But it is showing some error in .on() method of JQUERY while running this in IE8. kindly help me in this problem.

Here the sample code in [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXEbLL)

error showing in the following code

```
 this.$fileInput.on("change.cropit", this.onFileChange.bind(this));
        this.$preview.on(Cropit.PREVIEW_EVENTS, this.onPreviewEvent.bind(this));
        this.$zoomSlider.on(Cropit.ZOOM_INPUT_EVENTS, this.onZoomSliderChange.bind(this));
        if (this.options.allowDragNDrop) {
            this.$preview.on("dragover.cropit dragleave.cropit", this.onDragOver.bind(this));
            return this.$preview.on("drop.cropit", this.onDrop.bind(this));
        }
```

THE ERROR IS SHOWING ONLY IN IE8. Thanks in advance

Comment: I am using jQuery 1.11.3 version

Comment: could you please suggest any versions

Comment: 1.11.3 should work with IE8. The support for IE8 (and less) has only been dropped for version 2.x: http://jquery.com/browser-support/

Comment: Yes, jquery 1.12 is the last release supporting ie6... what's the error exactly?

Comment: Here the error
`Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 173
Char: 13
Code: 0`

Comment: hmm, it's an IE8 js error, not much point in asking ...

Comment: can you tell us which line in the example this error refers to?

Comment: line 173 .please check the error msg

Comment: How did you get CodePen to even work in IE8? I loaded an old XP box with IE8, and CodePen won't even run. JS errors everywhere.

Comment: @SiVi - which line of your example code posted in the question I mean, there are only seven lines! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I loaded an XP box with IE 8. CodePen doesn't run at all, and neither do the other major sandboxes like JSFiddle or JSBin. So, I took the code from CodePen (in a working box) and put it in a static HTML file. Next, I linked to the [proper Cropit source file](https://github.com/scottcheng/cropit/tree/master/dist) (not vendor.js which may have been taken from their PR page), and the first error encountered is not with jQuery, but with Cropit itself:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', {
  value: true
});
```

> Object doesn't support this property or method

[image: error]

With further research it turns out that IE8 has limited support for `defineProperty()`. In fact, from this [ECMA compatibility site](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/), IE8 struggles with most `Object` properties.

The problem is not with what jQuery version you are using, it's IE8. You just have to discontinue support for it like [Microsoft will](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search/default.aspx?sort=PN&alpha=Windows%20Internet%20Explorer%208&Filter=FilterNO).

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine in IE8 (real version)

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    this.$fileInput.on("change.cropit", this.onFileChange.bind(this));
        this.$preview.on(Cropit.PREVIEW_EVENTS, this.onPreviewEvent.bind(this));
        this.$zoomSlider.on(Cropit.ZOOM_INPUT_EVENTS, this.onZoomSliderChange.bind(this));
        if (this.options.allowDragNDrop) {
            this.$preview.on("dragover.cropit dragleave.cropit", this.onDragOver.bind(this));
            return this.$preview.on("drop.cropit", this.onDrop.bind(this));
        }
});
</script>
```